# Difference between npx create-react-app and create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npx

What is the difference between `npx create-react-app` and `create-react-app`?

React document says do `npx creat-react-app` but i see a tutorial in youtube and he say do `create-react-app`

I tried both of them and both work correctly

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`npx` will download the package `create-react-app`, run it once, then delete it from your disk. If you already have the package installed via `npm install -g create-react-app`, you can simply run `create-react-app` in your terminal.

It is recommended to use `npx`, because it doesn't clog up your filesystem, and because it will always use a package's latest version.

You can learn more from it on the [official documentation](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-npx-nodejs-package-runner).

Comment: official documentation changed: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx